# Show that a dashed curve is not a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, surfaces, submanifold

[image]

I have to show that the following curve is not a submanifold. I tried to define this as a set, as the spiral logarithm, but the "dots" block me..

My definition of a submanifold is : $M$ is a submanifold iff

$$ \forall x \in M \mbox{, } \exists U \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \mbox{, } \exists f : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \mbox{, } M \cap U = f^{-1} \left( \left\{ 0 \right\} \right)  $$

where $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ and $f$ a submersion in $x$.

Thanks you.

EDIT : I have to give a geometric proof.

Comment: It's not clear what the actual curve is.

Comment: Does the "center point" belong to the set or not ?

Comment: If the center point belongs to the set, then consider the fact that manifolds are locally contractible.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe yes

Comment: @Tohiea Try to prove that the definition of a submanifold is not satisfied at this precise point.

Comment: Okay i will try this, Thanks you all of you.

Comment: Please define the actual set. Your picture is suggestive, but not definitive.

Comment: I think that the question was poorly-formulated. I don't know how.. but writing a proof without the equation of the curve is quite difficult (as you said). This is a geometric proof that has to be done. If we take a neighborhood on the curve it is locally a submanifold. But if we take a neighborhood on a dot, obviously it is not a submanifold. So, the curve is not a submanifold... It is correct?